# Split text in all lines inside of a string

Tags: vb.net, split

- Originally the Keywords will we pulled out from a text file located on a web server.

Dim KeyWords As String = Split(Split(TempSMTPFile, "# Keywords #")(1), "# Keywords #")(0)

I want to create a function  that will split out all the keywords inside a string

```
The keywords in this example will be: 

' This list might be changed to more or less keywords.

     Dim KeyWords As String = "[One=Test1]" & vbNewLine & "[Two=Test2]" & vbNewLine & "[Three=Test3]"

        ' I Need a function to split out all keywords and do below check between all splits.

        If KeyWords.ToLower.Contains("[" & Splited_keyword & "=") Then ' One, Two, Three
            MsgBox(Split(Split(KeyWords, "[" & Splited_keyword & "=")(1), "]")(0)) ' Test1, Test2, Test3
        End If

        ' This should print OneTest1, TwoTest2, ThreeTest3
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a `Dictionary(of string, string)` instead?

Comment: Hello. As the keywords are not hardcoded into the application but will change over time based on a text file located on a web server I'm not sure if this function will be a good solution?

Comment: You can build a dictionary based on the text file too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments, I was able to solve this with this solution.

```
    Dim str As String() = keywords.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbCrLf)})
        For Each s As String In str

            If s.Contains("[") Then
                Dim SplittedKeyword = Split(Split(s, "[")(1), "=")(0)
                If TextUserShortDescription.Text.ToLower.Contains(SplittedKeyword.ToLower) Then
                    MsgBox(SplittedKeyword & (Split(Split(s, "[" & SplittedKeyword & "=")(1), "]")(0)))
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you (untested):

```
Dim keyValues as String()

keyValues = KeyWords.Split(Environment.NewLine)

For Each (keyvalue as string in keyValues)
    MsgBox(keyvalue.SubString(1, keyvalue.IndexOf("["c) + " " + keyvalue.SubString(keyvalue.IndexOf("="c), keyvalue.LastIndexOf("]"c)
End For
```

Comment: Hello. I did not get this to work. Im very new to split of string so i might be doing something wrong. 

Had to change code due to option strict:


            Dim keyValues As String()
            keyValues = KeyWords.Split(CType(Environment.NewLine, Char()))
            For Each keyvalue As String In keyValues
                MsgBox(keyvalue.Substring(1, CInt(keyvalue.IndexOf("["c) & CDbl(keyvalue.Substring(keyvalue.IndexOf("="c), keyvalue.LastIndexOf("]"c))))))
            Next